# What (if anything) is the difference between propositional constants and propositional variables in first-order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm taking a class on set theory, and we're beginning with a review of first-order logic. I did first-order logic a long time ago. I can now no longer remember if there is an important difference between propositional constants and propositional variables. Having Googled around a bit, it seems that these terms get used interchangeably quite often, but maybe there *is* some distinction I need to be aware of.

Perhaps some context about why I'm asking would help. We're doing the syntax of FOL right now, and in our syntax we have:

- Variables = {x, y, z,}
- Connectives = {¬, ∧, ∨, →, ↔, ∀x, ∃x}
- Predicates = {P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, =}
- Function symbols = {*f*i : i ≤ n}

The prof asked where 'constants' and 'propositional variables' go. I take it that by 'constant' the prof means 'individual constant' (AKA 'names,' 'individuals'). And I think these are going to be 0-ary function symbols. Now, I'm trying to figure out what he means by 'propositional variables' and where these things might go. Does he just mean "Where do things like P and Q in propositions of the form 'P → Q' go?" I think that's *probably* what he means, but I'm used to calling P and Q 'propositional constants' rather than 'propositional variables.' I have never encountered the term 'propositional variable' before, and searching around to see if there is a distinction between propositional constants and propositional variables has been unilluminating. Some people seem to suggest so, although I cannot understand why, while others seem to use the phrases interchangeably. Given this, I'm having a hell of a time guessing what the prof means by asking us where propositional variables fit into our syntax.

Comment: Hint: Think about propositional variables as the special case with arity 0 in the same way you correctly thought of individual constants as a special case of function symbols with arity 0. What kind of existing symbol would be suitable for this?

Comment: Hm. My hunch is that maybe by “propositional variables,” he does just mean what I learned as “propositional constants” (AKA sentence letters). And if that’s right, maybe they’d be predicates of a certain sort in FOL. But I’m not sure I really understand why — just taking shots in the dark here.

Comment: I'm coming around to understanding. How does the following sound? Constants count as 0-ary functions because what a function is is a mapping from a variable to a value. With no variable (i.e. with a o-ary function), we just get a value, which we can think of as a name. Re: propositional variables, they count as 0-ary predicates for purely syntactic reasons. If we want to have P and Q stand for atomic propositions in FOL for some reason, grammatically we can treat them just like predicates with no arguments and fit them in that way. There's no 'deeper' reason for treating them this way.

Comment: Yes, correct, we can see $P$ and $Q$ as a natural extension of predicates to the 0 case, and write them as $P$ instead of $P()$ for convenience.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I feel like I have a good grasp of this now.